How are array bounds ordered in C?
Suppose I have a 2d array like so:
int arr[4][5];

is this the equivalent of an array of 5 elements where each element is an array with 4 elements, or the other way around?
How would indexing work as well?
arr[4][3]; // is this the valid way of getting the most last element?
arr[3][4]; // or this?

I don't know how to properly test which one is correct, because I think C just allows going out of bounds anyway.

What beginners learning material are you studying? It should be taught in that. I also recommend that you check e.g. cdecl.org to see what it says about it.

A declaration in C gives a “picture” of how a variable will be used.1 So int arr[4][5]; says arr[i][j] will be an int.
In order for arr[i][j] to be an int, arr[i] must be an array of int, and so arr must be an array of arrays of int.
The array size expressions break the picture metaphor a little; we will never use arr[4] of an array declared as arr[4]; we will only use indices 0 to 3. However, the size does goes with the index: A declaration of int arr[4][5] associated with a use of arr[i][j] also associates the 4 bound with i and the 5 bound with j.
So arr[3][4] is the last element, and arr is an array of 4 arrays of 5 int.
Bonus

I think C just allows going out of bounds anyway.

Yes, the C standard “allows” going out of bounds in that it does not stop you from writing expressions that use array elements beyond the bounds of the array. But the standard does not define what happens when a program does that. The C standard is not a walled garden that you cannot leave. It is an open town with defined services in town and no guarantees about what is outside of town, but you are free to come and go.
Footnote
1 Kernighan and Ritchie, The C Programming Language, 1978, page 90.

C does not have n-dimensional arrays, only arrays of arrays.
int a[4][5] is an array of 4 arrays of 5 int elements.

because I think C just allows going out of bounds anyway.

Not really. It does not check, but accessing an element out of the array bounds invokes Undefined Behaviour

arr[3][4]; // or this?

Yes that is the last element

arr[4][3];

It is invokes UB as one of the indexes in out-of-bounds

What you have is equivalent to
typedef int A5[5]; // the type A5 denotes an array of 5 ints
A5 arr[4]; // arr is an array of 4 A5s ... ie an array of 4 (array of 5 ints)

